# Python Ctypes Null Terminated String Block

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using a ctypes implementation of [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx), and everything works well except I cannot figure out how to handle this section:

> A pointer to an environment block for the new process. If this parameter is NULL, the new process uses the environment of the calling process.
>
> An environment block consists of a null-terminated block of null-terminated strings. Each string is in the following form:
>
> name=value\0

To generated the raw string I execute the following:

```
lpEnvironment = '\0'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, os.environ[k]) for k in os.environ]) + '\0\0'
print lpEnvironment
'XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority\x00MUTT_DIR=/home/username/.mutt\x00LASTDIRFILE=/home/username/.lastpwd-geany\x00LOGNAME=username\...\x00\x00'
```

However run I make a ctypes variable out of it, it truncates the information:

```
ctypes.c_wchar_p(lpEnvironment)
c_wchar_p(u'XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority')
```

How can I pass the lpEnvironment information correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the whole string does get passed across the `ctypes` boundary correctly in one direction, but gets truncated on the way back.

```
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer('abc\0def').value
'abc'
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer('abc\0def').raw
'abc\x00def'
```

Unfortunately (at least for me, Python 2.6.5 on Linux) the result of `create_unicode_buffer` doesn't have a `.raw` property.  However,

```
>>> ctypes.wstring_at(ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(u'abc\0def), 7)
u'abc\x00def'
```

works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the raw property.

Comment: `''.join(ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(u'abc\0def'))` works, too.