# Null character in unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, ctypes

I know the code in C is this:

```
WCHAR string[] = L"string\0";
```

So I tried (in Python):

```
string = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer("String\0")
```

But this strips the Null character of or something.
If I use `create_string_buffer` it does work.

```
string = ctypes.create_string_buffer("String\0")
```

Now the the string has 2 Null characters at the end of it:

```
>>> string.raw
'String\x00\x00'
```

So why does this not work for unicode?

**Edit:**

This works (source: [Python Ctypes Null Terminated String Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393537/python-ctypes-null-terminated-string-block)):

```
string = ctypes.wstring_at(ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(u'string\0'), 7)
```

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016005/add-null-character-to-string-in-python

Comment: Nope, but it is of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393537/python-ctypes-null-terminated-string-block

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely.  Note the single-parameter init of `create_unicode_buffer` nul-terminates:

```
>>> r=ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('String\0Other')
>>> r.value              # value display stops at first nul.
u'String'
>>> ''.join(r)           # gives answer similar to create_string_buffer's raw method.
u'String\x00Other\x00'
```

Comment: I already found a hackish way to do it, but this seems cleaner. Thnx!